# Hand over a touch event from a view to one of its subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I want to trigger a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to a UIView subclass when the initial position of the touch is outside of the view (A below) of the UIView subclass. I have the following situation:

```
/-------------------/
| B                 |
|            /---/  |
|            | A |  |
|            /---/  |
|      C            |
|                   |
/-------------------/
```

A is the UIView that has the Pan gesture recognizer attached to it, B is the superview of A, and C is the initial position of the touch. The touch is then moved into A, and now I want A to take over the handling of the touch and the Pan recognizer to recognize the gesture and trigger its callback function.

As I understand B is returned by the initial hitTest:ing and thus will trigger the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Changed: handling of the touch.

How can I make the gesture recognizer of A "take over" the touch handling of this touch? Or at least receive the touches so that it may recognize the pan gesture?

My goal is to make this work when I track several touches at the same time in the situation  when there are several subviews like A around, so that the touch may be "handed over" to anyone of these.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be as "clean" as what you are looking for, but the best way that I can think of to do what you want is to add the gesture recognizer to superview "B", and then have "B" loop over its subviews to see when the gesture is inside a particular subview and then send messages to that subview to perform the desired action.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think the way you're suggesting is the most straightforward way. I will try to do this overriding the touchesBegan/Moved/EndedCancelled: functions in the superview "B". This way I guess that I can track several pan gestures at the same time. Otherwise I need several PanGestrureRecognizers, won't I?

Comment: You would need several gestures, and I'm also not sure that it is possible to do what you are asking. I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that if you drag a finger from "B" into "A", that "touch" is still owned by "B" and will not be recognized in "A" as a gesture. I think that you can still use a gesture recognizer, but just add it to "B" and not to the subviews. Using a gesture recognizer is a little bit easier than the low level touch routines.

Comment: I've got it working with one gesture recognizer attached to "B". I tried your suggestion since it is possibly easier than the low level touch routines. I can only move one of the "A" views at each time using this approach, i.e., the single gesture recognizer attached to "B" is only fired once (as I expected). The gesture is owned by B but on the first entry over an "A"-view I chose to store a pointer to that view as an instance variable in "B" and thus I only need to hit test until I find an "A" and then I stick to it until the pan gesture finishes.